# Combining ffmpeg operations -- can't seem to get the syntax right

Tags: ffmpeg

my purpose with `ffmpeg` is (and in this particular order)

1. reducing the video in size to 1920x1080 (1080P)
2. putting our logo on the top/right
3. putting a label between second 3 and 11 on the lower right corner

for this we run two `ffmpeg` commands in sequence.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black'  -preset slow -crf 18 temp.mp4
```

then...

```
ffmpeg -i temp.mp4 -i out_logo.png  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40,drawtext=text='This Is Our Label':fontfile=Some-Font.ttf:fontcolor=#3A3D34:alpha='if(lt(t,3),0,if(lt(t,4),(t-3)/1,if(lt(t,11),1,if(lt(t,12),(1-(t-11))/1,0))))':fontsize=35:box=1:boxcolor=#DDD6D0@1:boxborderw=25:x=60:y=h-th-60:enable='between(t,3,12)'" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart final.mp4
```

This two lines work well for us, but I'm trying to optimize processing speed....

All my attempts to run this in a single command and keep order have failed with `ffmpeg` complaining about syntax, like putting the `-vf 'scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black'  -preset slow -crf 18` in front of the `-filter_complex`.

Is there a way to do this with a single command?

Answer (score 0):

There is: You need to label the filter chain:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4  -i out_logo.png  -filter_complex "

[0:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1:color=black[vtemp]
;
[vtemp][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-40:40,drawtext=text='This Is Out Label':fontfile=Some-Font.ttf:fontcolor=#3A3D34:alpha='if(lt(t,3),0,if(lt(t,4),(t-3)/1,if(lt(t,11),1,if(lt(t,12),(1-(t-11))/1,0))))':fontsize=35:box=1:boxcolor=#DDD6D0@1:boxborderw=25:x=60:y=h-th-60:enable='between(t,3,12)'[vout]

" -map '[vout]' -map 0:a
-c:a copy -movflags +faststart final.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, it outputs -- `Output with label '0:a' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.`

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: `0:a` is the audio of first file - in this example `original.mp4` - if this has no audio, then you need to drop all audio related stuff from the command line. Important: You need `0:a` and *not* `[0:a]` (i.e. no square brackets)